# Javascript Date toString convert and format to local time

Tags: javascript

I have a script that gets a date/time in the the format of:

```
2017-06-15 21:00
```

and then converts it to local time and displays as:

```
Thu Jun 15 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plg-date > .fabrikElement > div').each(function() {
        var date = $(this).text();
        var newdate = new Date(date + " UTC");
        console.log(newdate);
        $(this).text(newdate.toString());
    })
})
```

How would I format the toString so the output was something like this?

```
Thu Jun 15 2017 5:00:00 PM Eastern Daylight Time
```

Comment: Take a look at [date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), the options it accepts, and the example where you set undefined as the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use an external library, I'd suggest this one liner using [momentjs](//momentjs.com/):

```
moment('2017-06-15 21:00').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY h:mm:ss A')
// => "Thu Jun 15 2017 9:00:00 PM"
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to parse it yourself. There are libraries that can do it as well (Stack Overflow rules advise not making recommendations, but if you Google "javascript date format library" a bit you'll find them), but if you want to do it with plain JavaScript, you'll just need to build the string yourself.

Since you're already creating a `Date` object, you're half way there.

The `Date` object only has numbers, so it won't have strings for things like `Thu`, `Jun` and `Eastern Daylight Time`. For those, you'll need lists of possible values and to map the numbers to them (usually a simple array will work).

For the `5:00:00 PM` part, you can mod (`%`) the hours by 12, and then specify `AM` if `hours < 12` or `PM` if `hours >= 12`.

```
const time = (d.getHours() % 12) + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + (d.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
```

I won't give you the full JavaScript because you should take a stab at writing it yourself. If you have any trouble, please ask another question.

You can also use combinations of [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), but it won't do everything you need (it doesn't do 12-hour date format, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Using @James suggestion to use toLocaleString()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plg-date > .fabrikElement > div').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().length > 0) {
            var date = $(this).text();
            var newdate = new Date(date + " UTC");
            var options = { 
                year: 'numeric', 
                month: 'numeric', 
                day: 'numeric',
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            }
            $(this).text(newdate.toLocaleString('en-US', options)); 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: although I appreciate the answers above, I really do not like using plugins. So this was the most reasonable compromise.