# Displaying date object as react child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I've started with react hooks(new programmer) since everybody said it is easier to start with, i'm trying to print on the screen `deliverydate` but react does not accept object as react child, is there easy solution? This is what I have:

`<p>{something?.something2?.deliveryDate}</p>`

I'm trying to get this:

`deliveryDate: Tue Mar 09 2021 13:10:04 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) {}`

I get this error: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Tue Mar 09 2021 13:10:04 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Just get the string representation of the Date object: `<p>{something?.something2?.deliveryDate.toString()}</p>`.

Comment: @zhulien how to not get the end text this one 'GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'

Comment: Either use `.toGMTString()`, `.toDateString()` or `.toUTCString()` depending on your use case instead of `.toString()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Date toString convert and format to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806442/javascript-date-tostring-convert-and-format-to-local-time)

Comment: @zhulien how to accept your comment as an answer ?

Comment: @walee You can't accept comments. Accept Tom's answer as he is basically the same as my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass react something it does know how to render, like a string. So if `deliveryDate` is a Date then

```
<p>{something?.something2?.deliveryDate.toString()}</p>
```

will work. If you want that exact format, you might need to use something like moment.js

Comment: Cleford how to not get this one from it  'GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

Comment: What exactly do you want to render?

Answer (score 0):

you have **date** Type - so first need to parse object date to another type(number or text)

The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

```
const test = Date.parse(something?.something2?.deliveryDate)
console.log(test)
```

Edit:
Or another conversion :

```
something?.something2?.deliveryDate.toString();
```

Comment: The author already has a date object. What are you talking about? Why should he parse the object?! He just needs the string representation.

Comment: a - ok - i mean the type parse - your right - object is object, and not string